# Good literature on Progress 4GL

Tags: progress-4gl

I am in search for good literature to learn Progress 4GL. This is a workspace-related project, and funding for training is not available. I've tried the documentation, but it is inaccurate and pretty chaotic.

I will have to do most work in the ChUI on OE 10.1B.

I am aware of several books that are available on lulu.com. Which ones are actually good?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at QUE Books. They had a book written for Version 8. It is out f print but maybe someone has it.

Gary Mittleman
garym@camgar.ca

Answer (score 5):

For "cookbook" answers you should probably go to one of the Progress focused online forums.  The "official" site is http://communities.progress.com/pcom/index.jspa but traffic on general programming subjects is fairly light and there is virtually no participation from PSC itself.  http://www.peg.com/lists/ is much more active.  There is also http://progresstalk.com.

Answer (score 4):

If you are working in a character environment then the older books are probably most suitable.  Newer documentation will tend to focus on GUI environments and thus probably won't meet your needs.  The character environment hasn't changed and so the old stuff is still good,

"Making Good Progress" is a tome but it was released when GUI was new and there was still a lot of character stuff:

http://www.wss.com/publications/books.html

Of course if you are working in a character environment you are also probably working within a specific application partners environment and they will have their own framework and coding conventions that you will also need to learn.  That sort of thing has to come from the partner.

Comment: > within a specific application partners environment

... (thankfully|unfortunately), nope, this is a completely homebrew application that was created in the last twenty years layer upon layer ... Pretty crazy stuff sometimes, some legacy chaos that was added to please the users... the horror ;) 

Thanks for the literature pointers :)

Answer (score 3):

having worked in that language for several years, I recommend the documentation.  Progress publishes a series of about 30 books which document their language, and which cover most topics in (usually) good depth.  I never needed a third party book with the full progress docs available.

Comment: Agreed, I've always found the Progress documentatio to be sufficient. Which is fortunate as all the 3rd party books I've seen are out of print....

Comment: Another valuable resource is the Progress online knowledge base.  If the docs don't clearly explain something, the knowledge base usually takes up the slack.

Comment: That online knowledge base is somewhat more professional than what I am looking for unfortunately. I need more of a O'Reilly-style "Progress ABL Cookbook" dokumentation which covers stuff like "how do I sort a browse by FieldName"... 

Thanks for your input, though.